# Why do I not have amenities?

Tags: civilization-6

From the picture below, this city has truffles and salt.  Truffles have a camp on them and salt has a mine.  Why does the scree still say 0 amenities from luxury resources?  From what I can tell I did not trade them away, because I can still trade them.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Civ 6 replacing happiness with Amenities it also changed how that is awarded. You must now improve the tile to gain it's benefit for the amenity and the second thing to note is that ALL of your amenities will be shared across ALL of your cities automatically. So it would appear that overall, you do not have enough.

Hope this helps.

Edit: 1 luxury resource = 4 amenities.

Comment: When you say improve the title, wouldn't that be a mine on salt and camp on truffles.. I have 8 cities so I need 2 of each, good to know, but how do these amenities get distributed?  By order of creation?  Or is the game smart enough to know if a city has enough then give the left overs to other cities?

Comment: Essentially what I've seen from my own games so far is that the cities that generate the amenities will hold onto them if they are not required elsewhere, which will grant a bonus to both growth and NON food yields and when they are needed elsewhere it distributes them as needed. If one city has +3 and you build another city that would potentially have -1, it would make it 0/+2.  By improved tiles I do mean Camp etc yes.